# How do I limit the amount of child div's displayed inline?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to use CSS3 to limit the amount of child div's displayed in a row (or in-line)?

```
<div class="parent">

  <div class="child">
    <img>
    <p>Text explaining img</p>
  </div>

  <div class="child">
    <img>
    <p>Text explaining another img</p>
  </div>

  <!-- If I only want two per line, let's push the next two down -->

  <div class="child">
    <img>
    <p>Text explaining another img</p>
  </div>

  <div class="child">
    <img>
    <p>Text explaining another img</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

I've considered just applying widths and margins, but I would also want the last child in a row to have margin-right:0;

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the size of your elements, you could do it this way:

```
.parent {
    border: 2px solid #c00;
    padding: 4px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.child {
    border: 2px solid #0c0;
    padding: 4px;
    display: block;
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    margin: 0 76px 0 0;
}
.child:nth-child(2n) {
    margin: -76px 0 0 76px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b4f5c/

Comment: Thanks!  Although I'm shooting for a liquid layout, I was able to just convert to em.

Comment: If you'd like to change the number of items that will display beside each other you could even extend this to `3n` or `4n` with media queries determining the style that should be used based on screen-width.

Answer (score 0):

> You should use jquery or javascript to display next 2 children

**css3 has [nth-child property](http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/)** but you can display the specific children only with this property.

This is the solution with jquery

```
var dispdivs=0;
  function minview()
     $(".child").hide();// hide all child elements
     dispdivs+=2; 
      for(var i=0;i<dispdivs;i++) //this is to display extra 2 divs
      {
       $(".child:eq("+i+")").show();
      }
    }
```

when ever you want to show all elements use

```
$(".child").show();
```